# How to define a map with key as a enum and value as an integer in c++11/c++14?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, enums, c++14

```
enum Symbols
{
    BAR,
    BELL,
    PLUM,
    ORANGE,
    CHERRY,
    DOESNOTMATTER,
}wheel1, wheel2, wheel3;

map<Symbols[3], int> symb = {{{BAR, BAR, BAR}, 250},
                              {{BELL, BELL, BELL}, 20},
                              {{BELL, BELL, BAR}, 20},
                              {{PLUM, PLUM, BAR}, 14},
                              {{PLUM, PLUM, PLUM}, 14},
                              {{ORANGE, ORANGE, BAR}, 10},
                              {{ORANGE, ORANGE, ORANGE}, 10},
                              {{CHERRY, CHERRY, CHERRY}, 7},
                              {{CHERRY, CHERRY, DOESNOTMATTER}, 5},
                              {{CHERRY, DOESNOTMATTER, DOESNOTMATTER}, 2}};
```

I have defined an enumerator named Symbols. I am trying to create a map, who's key is a Symbols enum array and value is an integer.

When I try to run this program, I get an error "**/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/utility:268:11: Array initializer must be an initialiser list**".

What am I doing wrong here? I have tried inserting the values too. The error is the same.

Comment: I will try that right away.

Comment: I get this error now - " /Users/ashwinvprabhu/Documents/Work/C++/Test/TestPrograms/TestPrograms/main.cpp:25:29: No matching constructor for initialization of 'map<array<Symbols, 3>, int>' ".

Comment: I am trying to create a slot machine game,  and I need this dictionary to determine the prize. Is there any other library which u can suggest in place of map?

Comment: Instead of using `Symbols[3]` just use `struct S { Symbols s[3]; };`.

Answer (score 4):

The raw array `Symbols[3]` doesn't match the requirement of the containers as a key type of [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

> std::map meets the requirements of Container, AllocatorAwareContainer, AssociativeContainer and ReversibleContainer.

See [C++ concepts: Container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container)

```
CopyInsertable
EqualityComparable
Destructible
```

You can use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Such as:

```
std::map<std::array<Symbols, 3>, int> symb = ...
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/KBV8262)

Comment: map need also lessComparable for key

Comment: See : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/AssociativeContainer cause map is not a container, but an associative container

Comment: @Garf365 : Both `std::vector` and `std::array` provide lexicographical `operator<` out of the box.

Comment: @ildjarn I agree with you, it was just to complete requirements for map

Answer (score 1):

The reason you cannot do this is because the raw arrays are not copyable or assignable, and copy operation is required for `map`, `vector`, `set`, etc. 
Use this instead:

```
std:array<Symbol,3>
```

Comment: They are also not equality comparable in a way that would be desirable in a map.

Comment: @melak47 to be pedantic, `std::map` requires the type to be comparable with strict ordering.

Comment: @user2079303 That's not even what I mean - given `int a[3];` and `int b[3];`, you can certainly compare them: `a < b`. But ordering them by address is probably not very useful...

Comment: @melak47 My point was that key types in a map don't have to support `operator==`. In other words the type doesn't need to be equality comparable. But I don't disagree with you otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

For map, Key need at least to be :

- Copiable
- less Comparable

To achieve this, I will pass by a structure :

```
struct key
{
    Symbol k1;
    Symbol k2;
    Symbol k3;

    key(Symbol _k1, Symbol _k2, Symbol _k3):
        k1(_k1), k2(_k2), k3(_k3)
    {}
    key(key const &) = default;
    key(key &&) = default;
    key &operator=(key const &) = default;
    key &operator=(key &&) = default;

    bool operator<(key const & rhs)
    {
       // perform less operation between this and rhs
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <array>

enum Symbols
{
  BAR,
  BELL,
  PLUM,
  ORANGE,
  CHERRY,
  DOESNOTMATTER,
};

void main()
{
  std::map<std::array<Symbols,3>, int> symb ( { 
    { { Symbols::BAR, Symbols::BAR, Symbols::BAR }, 250 }
  } );
  std::array<Symbols, 3> bar_sym = { Symbols::BAR, Symbols::BAR, Symbols::BAR };
  std::cout << symb[bar_sym] << std::endl;
  }
```