# map.insert: "Invalid arguments" error with pair<enum,vector<*>>

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, enums

*EDIT 4: Ok, I narrowed the problem down to a small cpp file giving the same error message which everyone can reproduce:*

```
#include<vector>
#include<map>
using namespace std;

namespace{enum class Colors{Black,White};}

class dummyClass{};

class MapTest
{
    vector<dummyClass*> Dummys;
    map<Colors,vector<dummyClass*>> dummyMap;
public:
    MapTest()
    {
        Dummys.push_back(new dummyClass);
        Dummys.push_back(new dummyClass);
        dummyMap.insert(make_pair(Colors::White,Dummys));
    }
    ~MapTest()
    {
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<Dummys.size();++i)
        {
            delete Dummys[i];
        }
        Dummys.clear();
        dummyMap.clear();
    }

};

int main()
{
    MapTest m;
}
```

*EDIT 3: In case anyone wonders. I delete all Pointers in the destructor. Didn't post it since I figured it's not relevant to the problem*

*EDIT 2: Added more details in the .cpp file. The classes "Bauer" and "Position" shouldn't be of any relevance.*

My header file match.h:

```
#include <map>
#include"Bauer.h"
class Match
{
    int counter{0};
    std::vector<Figuren*> allFiguresWhite;
    std::vector<Figuren*> allFiguresBlack;
    std::map<Farben,std::vector<Figuren*>> samePlayerFig;
    std::map<Farben,std::vector<Figuren*>> otherPlayerFig;
   //more code...
}
```

"Farben" is just a enum : `enum class Farben{black, white};` 
In my match.cpp I try at one point to insert a par into the map:

```
#include "match.h"
using namespace std;

Match::Match()
{
    cout<<"Let the games begin\n";
    InitGame();
}

void Match::InitGame()
{
    for(int i=1;i<9;i++)
    {
        allFiguresWhite.push_back(new Bauer(Position{2,i},Farben::white, counter++));
        allFiguresBlack.push_back(new Bauer(Position{7,i},Farben::black,counter++));
    }
    samePlayerFig.insert(make_pair(Farben::white,allFiguresWhite));
    //more code...
}
```

Unfortunately I get the compiler error "Invalid arguments' " in this line with "insert" beeing underlined in red.
Any idea what I did wrong?

EDIT:
Here is the complete error message

> Invalid arguments ' Candidates are:
>   std::pair>>>,bool>
>   insert(const std::pair>> &) std::pair>>>,bool>
>   insert(#10000 &&) void insert(std::initializer_list>>>)
>   std::_Rb_tree_iterator>>> insert(std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator>>>, const
>   std::pair>> &) std::_Rb_tree_iterator>>> insert(std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator>>>, #10000 &&)
>   void insert(#10000, #10000) ' match.cpp   /chessGame  line 17 Semantic
>   Error

Comment: Compile it and paste the real error message into the question. (Don't rely on IntelliSense for the truth; it provides more plausible guesses than facts.)

Comment: Cannot reproduce with what you gave us, show us the real code where you call this.

Comment: Please refer this:: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35452739/how-to-define-a-map-with-key-as-a-enum-and-value-as-an-integer-in-c11-c14)

Comment: @ChVKishore: Thx for the link, but since I'm not using a raw array it shouldn't be the cause of the error, right? As far as I understand the underlyingtype of an enum is int.

Comment: BTW you are having epic memory leaks with your `vector` with your `new`. C++ *requires* manual freeing of memory

Comment: @PasserBy: I know, I do that in the destructor. Since it's not relevant I didn't post it.

Comment: Try `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: thx, but unfortunately that doesn't change anything. Like I said, I do all the relevant stuff (delete pointer, clear vector etc.) in the destructor. The error message doesn't seem to be related to memory leaks

Comment: Can't reproduce https://godbolt.org/g/ToSxss (from EDIT 4). `class` -> `struct` btw to make it work.

Comment: Hmm, strange thing that is does compile. Maybe it's a Eclipse specific problem. I'm actually using gcc 6.2.0 too. Btw, just forgot the "public" keyword, edited it, error still here.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, It seems to be a Eclipse specific error. I compiled the Test programm from the command line using "g++ main.cpp -o main" and it works fine. Gonna look into it why it doesn't work on eclipse. So far I've compiled a lot of projects and never had any compiler issues.

Comment: I have the problem with every map constellation (<int, int>, <string, string>, ...).
Have you found a way for eclipse to build and run the project again?

Comment: I found a solution for my problem. My eclipse accepts "map[key] = value;".